# Using jQuery .each() to iterate through elements of one id for .attr() in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, each

I have a button for accessing the profile page on my site. I want to add a second button on the page. The site is in backbone.js, but these buttons are on the menu as part of my static index.html file.

Currently, I'm using jQuery's .attr() as so to make the link go to the proper profile:

```
self.$('#btn-profile').attr('href', '/profile/' + res.id);
```

Where res.id is the user's id number. The 'this' refers to the element 'body' in a backbone.js app. The code is in a view in backbone for the 'profile'.

When I add a second button, however, jQuery's .attr() only adjusts the first button's href. I need both buttons to refer to proper user profile, so I try to use .each() to iterate through the buttons, like so:

```
self.$('#btn-profile').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', '/profile/' + res.id);
})
```

Is there a reason this isn't working or is my error somewhere else, maybe to do with it being part of a View in Backbone? Thanks!

I did console.log(self); on the line above and self is [object Window] in the console. If I try to log it in the iteration function it only logs once.

Comment: because id of elements must be unique... if you want to group similar elements then use class attributes

Comment: then I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because id of elements must be unique... if you want to group similar elements then use class attributes... then use the class selector to select them